# List callable functions from GDB

Tags: c, gdb

Using GDB on the command line, I sometimes break at a certain line of code. At that breakpoint, I can then call functions *as if* my executable contained the call.

How can I get GDB to print the list of all the possible functions that are callable at a given breakpoint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could type `call` and then hit `<tab>` (until a list displays). This seems to list the functions contained in the binary.

Comment: There might be some configurations you can do to Cygwin to enable that. [This page](http://sourcery.dyndns.org/wiki.cgi?CygwinTips) (ctrl+f tab completion) says something about adding `"\t":menu-complete` to a .inputrc file.

Answer (score 1):

The whole list of callable functions can be rather large. For example it includes all libc functions. Instead, you can start typing function name and press `Tab` key to get shorter list. Also note that global variables and file names also will be listed along with functions.

```
(gdb) call 'open
open              open_memstream    openat.c          opendir.c
open64            open_path         openat64          opendir@plt
open64.c          open_socket       openat64.c        openlog
open64@plt        open_translit     openaux           openlog_internal
open64_2.c        open_verify       openaux_args      opensock.c
open_2.c          open_wmemstream   openchild.c       
open_catalog.c    openat            opendir
```